# Displaying content from different PHP app into one single PHP app

Tags: php, yii

I am creating a PHP app that will display some classifieds/listings based on user location. For eg:

**Our classifieds from Chicago**:

- Classified 1
- Classified 2
- Classified 3

now, I also want to display "classifieds" from some other classified sites into my own page. Like this:

More Classifieds from Chicago (courtsey of **XYZ.com**)

- Classified 1
- Classified 2
- Classified 3
- Classified 4

More Classifieds from Chicago (courtsey of **ABC.com**)

- Classified 1
- Classified 2
- Classified 3

This way, user can see classifieds hosted on my server AND as well as classifieds from other common classified sites.

Is it possible this? Note that 1) there are no "RSS" feeds available for importing these classifieds; and 2)if possible I'd like to show these lists in widget format. That is display a iframe/widget box (not sure what the technical term is) and display all external-classifieds in that box. 
See a rough mockup here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJpgA.jpg

I was thinking I could load the other classified sites into "iframes" but then I'd get the whole site (including their header/footer, logo etc.). I just want some relevant "classified" section from their site.

Comment: Do the sites expose their data via an API? If not, you'd probably be looking at screen scraping, which wouldn't be great. Also, have you checked their t+c's to make sure it is okay to use their data (assuming they don't have an API).

Comment: No RSS feeds and no API. Yeah, they are okay if I display their data on my site. I am not hosting their data, just displaying the classified's headlines and images. When someone clicks on headline, the user will be sent to their site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to look into doing some screen scraping through a spider and parser setup.  You can use CURL or file_get_contents to bring in the web page, then use regular expressions and string operators to filter out the data you want, then build a page to display it.  This is an overly simplified version of the full answer, but if i gave you the 100's of lines of code to complete this, that would be cheating!

Answer (score 0):

Given the lack of API or feed, the only thing I can think of is to have to pull the relevant URLs and scrape the data from them. It should be pretty simple with a mix of file_get_contents and DOMDocument to parse the data, as long as the markup is tidy.

Answer (score 0):

The best option i can think is set up a web crawler asynchronous that fetches the data from those sites.

You could set it up to crawl every day at 00:00 and store the content in your database, something like:

```
external_classified
id
site_source
city_id
extra_data
```

After that you could get it from your PHP app with no problems.

**EDIT**: Note that the solution i'm thinking is asynchronous! The other answers use an synchronous action to get the data. I think it's a waste of time to fetch the same classifies over and over again. Although, to be fair, those solutions are simpler to implement.

Comment: also, since he mentions Yii, he could use Yii's cache system to store the remote data, a good idea for any 3rd-party data.